# Access not finding an excel file which was created in vba on a network

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have code that opens & alters an excel table, saves it to a new (network) location, and then imports data from the newly formatted excel.  The issue I have is that the code can't find the newly created file, saying it doesn't exist.  I've played around with adding a 'pause' function, but I'm wondering if there's a way to refresh the network link in vba?  Or is there a better method?  Files will vary by size.

If I add a break in the code and let it sit for a few minutes it finds the file fine.

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click()

[other code]

'save excel file onto network location
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("\\network\file.xlsx")
xlApp.Quit

'Import file to temp table. 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblImport","\\network\file.xlsx", True
End sub
```

Run-time error '3011': The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '\network\file.xlsx'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Comment: If you have finished with Excel then after quitting use `Set xlApp = Nothing`. Free up any other Excel resources before this as well. I don't think this should be an issue, but may get you a step closer. A call to `DoEvents` after this wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free up the Excel resources when finished:

```
xlApp.Quit
'free any other Excel resources, then..
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

If it is a network issue and you need a delay then you can use `Application.OnTime`. For 15 seconds:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure"
```

This will run your procedure (my_Procedure()) after the delay, and this procedure can perform the import.

Comment: Thanks I had missed the Set xlApp = Nothing.  I don't like coding the delay into this as file size will vary quite drastically - and I'd have to set this to the maximum amount.

I'll change my workflow to process locally and copy the directory back to the network after all is done.  Thanks for the input.